# JS file is loaded but not being executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony

I have a project running on `Symfony` with `angular js` and its all working good except for a strange thing.

I added a `JavaScript` file to execute some `JQuery` functions i already tested in the browser console and they are all working good with no errors the problem is when I inspect element i can see the file being called in the head and i can also see it in the sources I can even open the link and see the file. 
But for some reason the functions in there are not being called executed.

following the images to prove that its loading with no errors.

Edit:
Its not about putting the code in ready function or not

[image: file accessed from browser]

[image: in head]

[image: in sources]

[image: no errors]

Comment: Are you using jQuery plugins in Angular project ?

Comment: alot of plugins yes and they are all working with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready` is firing before angular has loaded the content onto the page.

So it might be the possibility of your jQuery plugin calls before your Angular loads the content onto the page.

what you need to do is somehow, call your jQuery plugin once your Angular gets `init` or you can turns your code into directive.

Comment: if so then the code should work cuz this piece of code is not related to any angular code. and its listening to keyup and if you noticed i've putted the code outside ready function (also tried inside as i said in the question) both didnt work

Comment: You meant to say is this page doesn't has Angular code ? Can you create a small jsfiddle to understand the exact problem ?

Comment: the page have angular code but the code is not related to this JQuery one so it wont affect it 
it will be hard to create a fiddle alot of files are being called

Comment: and as i said i tried to put it outside the ready function so it wont be affected with the load of the page still not working :/

Comment: What I am saying is, if the HTML is rendered by the Angular code and jQuery plugin calls on that HTML element, at that time Angular code loads first and then jQuery plugins calls. It might cause the problem.

Comment: i will for sure

Comment: Glad to hear that, All the best:)

Answer (score 0):

My script file was also loading but not executing but I had a different issue, basically avoid using `href` attribute in script tag and instead use `src`